# Spring JMS using MarshallingMessageConverter while supporting String, etc

Tags: jaxb, spring-jms, jmstemplate

Using XML configuration - I have `MarshallingMessageConverter` working; however, I still want to send some messages as `TextMessage` with simple `String` values.

It seems that my configuration is forcing me to go from one ditch (No automatic JAXB marshalling) into the other (JAXB marshalling only):

Here's my relevant XML configuration:

```
<bean id="jaxbConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsListenerContainerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory">
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="jmsErrorHandler" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver"/>
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="jaxbConverter" />
</bean>
```

The JAXB marshalling works fine, but I sometimes want to send an empty body (header properties only) message; which causes an error like so:

```
.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
```

Which makes sense, because I'm sending a non-JAXB string (or nothing) in the body.

Is it possible to have the best of both worlds; the `String`, `byte[]`, `Map` conversion behavior of `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter` -and- `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter` ?

Is the only way to accomplish this by making a second container factory with the other converter and explicitly using it in my `@JmsListener` annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple `DelegatingMessageConverter`(implement `MessageConverter`) and have it delegate to the `SimpleMessageConverter`, `MarshallingMessageConverter` (or even a `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`) based on a message property, e.g. `message.getStringProperty("contentType")` - `text/plain`, `application/xml`, `application/json`.